# Оптимизировать регулярное выражение

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Написал регулярку для такого условия: 
первая буква - заглавная русская, затем пробел, затем 6 цифр. Пример:

> Г 666666

Регулярное выражение я записал следующим образом:

```
^[[А-Я]{1}[\\u0020]{1}[\\d]{6}]$
```

Требуется ли оптимизация данного регулярного выражения? И если да, то какая?

Comment: Так ведь эта регулярка не работает, почему вы говорите "оптимизировать"?

Answer (score 7):

Выражение [`^[[А-Я]{1}[\u0020]{1}[\d]{6}]$`](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyyr6du4d) находит только такую строку, которая состоит из одного символа (заглавной буквы, `{`, пробела, цифры, `}`), так как шаблон представляет собой неквантифицированный символьный класс со вложенными символьными классами (образуя так называемый "character class union", т.е. между этими символьными классами отношения типа ИЛИ), а квантификаторы тут распознаются как буквальные текст (`[{6}]` найдет `{`, `6` или `}`).

Вам нужно использовать

```
^[А-Я] \d{6}$
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/Pr0Kxm/1/)

**Если под "пробелом" понимается *любой* пробельный символ**, замените пробел в выражении `\s` и используйте флаг `(?U)` (тогда найдутся все пробелы Юникода):

```
(?U)^[А-Я]\s\d{6}$
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки (в методе `matches()` его можно опустить, так как совпадение должно совпадать со всей строкой)
- `[А-Я]` - русская заглавная буква
- - пробел (можете его записать как `\u0020`, но это нужно только если вы планируете добавить в выражение комментарии с помощью флага `Pattern.COMMENTS`, хотя и тогда можно написать `\`, т.е. экранировать пробел)
- `\d{6}` - 6 цифр (можно заменить на `[0-9]{6}`)
- `$` - конец строки.

Java-код:

```
Boolean matched = s.matches("[А-Я] \\d{6}"); // Если в строке разрешается простой пробел
Boolean matched = s.matches("[А-Я]\\s\\d{6}"); // Если в строке разрешены любые пробельные символы
```

Answer (score 2):

Квантификатор `{1}` можно не писать, поскольку по умолчанию и так проверяется единственное совпадение.

Для пробельных символов существует подстановка `\s`, которая работает независимо от параметров. При некоторых параметрах пробел в регулярном выражении используется для выделения разных частей и не принимает участие в проверке.

Результат: `[A-Я]\s\d{6}`.

Символы `^` и `$` нужно добавить, если вы хотите убедиться, что строка целиком совпадает с шаблоном.

Comment: `\s` находит не только пробел.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, я так и написал в своём ответе: [пробельный символ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Категория:Пробельные_символы).

Comment: А в вопросе используется `\\u0020`, т.е. пробел. Автор просит не менять, а улучшить шаблон.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, если автор посчитает, что я ему неправильно посоветовал, я думаю, он сам мне и напишет. И если это неправильно, зачем вы этот кусок скопировали в своей ответ?

Comment: `(?U)^[А-Я]\s\d{6}$` далеко не то же самое, что `[A-Я]\s\d{6}`, так как  флаг `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` позволяет находить ВСЕ пробельные символы из таблицы Юникода. Ваше решение не найдёт совпадения, если пробел в строке будет неразрывным (`\xA0`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Вы усложняете. В исходной задаче ничего про это нет. `\s` является общей практикой со времён Perl и скорее всего, подошло бы автору вопроса. Зачем вы тратите своё и моё мнение в бесплодных прениях, мне непонятно. Зачем вы мне пытаетесь доказать, что ваш ответ лучше? Это stack overflow, здесь много разных ответов на один вопрос это норма.